# Обьяснить задачу по теории вероятности

Tags: теория-вероятностей

Обсуждали в чате логическую задачу. Если подумать ответ очевиден. К сожалению мне попался товарищ, не понимающий этой очевидности и не поддающийся на попытки убеждения.

Сама задача:

1. Есть три сундука, в каждом из которых лежит по две монетки.
2. В первом — две золотых. Во втором — две серебрянных. В третьем — одна золотая и одна серебрянная.
3. Мы выбираем сундук случайным образом и вслепую вытаскиваем от туда монетку. Она оказывается золотой. Какова вероятность того, что следующая вытащенная из того же сундука монетка — тоже золотая?

Какой ответ получится у вас? Как объяснить решение этой задачи? Я даже приводил в пример подбрасывание монетки и предлагал провести эксперимент в реальности. Не помогло.

UPD: Помогите написать программу, рассчитывающую вероятность вытаскивания золотой монеты.

Comment: В этом сундуке осталась либо одна серебрянная монета, либо одна золотая, с равной вероятностью. Стало быть, 1/2.

Comment: раз уж тут SO, и на мете просили объяснять минусы - что вы пробовали чтобы решить задачу? какой ответ получился у вас? без этого вопрос - просто вброс в попытках заработать карму на задаче, ответ к которой, вместе очень подробными объяснениями, гуглится в два клика.

Comment: Что? _по большей части зависит от мнения_??? Ответ на этот вопрос **не зависит от мнения**. У вопроса есть чёткий, однозначный ответ, потому что это вопрос по математике.

Comment: @VladD ответ не зависит от мнения. Восприятие вопроса (и выбор правильного ответа) топикастером (и klopp) зависит от мнения. Точнее от их понимания слова "вероятность", которое, судя по поведению ТС, применимо только к событиям, которые еще не произошли. Поскольку ТС предпочитает использовать свое собственное понятие "вероятности" - то вопрос не основывается на  фактах, доказательствах или профессиональном опыте -> выбор "типа правильного" ответа зависит от мнения топикастера, а не от реальной правильности ответа.

Comment: @VladD хотите переоткрыть и закрыть как оффтопик?

Comment: @PashaPash: Например, дописать «плиз, помогите написать программу, которая проверяет/отвергает гипотезы».

Comment: @VladD это полностью поменяет задумку автора вопроса. Сейчас в теле ясно сказано что он знает правильный ответ, и что ему нужна помощь в объяснении этого ответа "товарищу". Менять основную суть вопроса редактированием вроде как нельзя. По мне так это просто была попытка запостить очередную "интересную задачу на логику", которая гарантирванно вызовет флейм. таким вообще на SO не место.

Comment: @PashaPash: Зато это спасёт вопрос. Что делать?

Comment: @VladD не кормить троллей. Автор знал, что вопрос вызовет флейм - ну вот пусть сам решает что ему делать.

Comment: Я за любой вариант, кроме удаления вопроса. Я вообще не понимаю, как ответ может зависеть от мнения пользователей и изначально считал, что получу единственно верный ответ.

Comment: @mikelsv: Тогда может быть, имеет способ добавить запрос на код? Это спасёт вопрос, по идее.

Comment: @VladD: добавил.

Comment: @mikelsv есть два ответа с кодом, один с теорией, один - на пальцах. Какого ответа вы ждете? С кодом, который выдаст 1/2, который вы отметите как верный? Он будет заведомо ложным. С кодом, который выдаст 2/3 на другом ЯП? Тогда укажите на каком именно. Перечитайте существующие ответы, выберите один, отметьте его как правильный. Иначе я не вижу смысла в переоткрытии.

Comment: @PashaPash: Три ответа с кодом.

Comment: @VladD тем более. и это ради тривиальной задачи в три строчки без кода.

Comment: @PashaPash: Тем не менее, у нас не получилось убедительно объяснить в три строчки. Так что частично и наш фейл.

Comment: @VladD бесполезно объяснять тому, кто не хочет слушать.

Comment: Я только сейчас в полной мере начал осознавать где был неправ. Обязательно выберу ответ, как только еще раз проанализирую все с самого начала. Есть ли название феномена, когда человек с убежденностью отстаивает неправильную точку зрения? )

Comment: А ведь в самом-то деле это **хороший** вопрос и он получил **хорошие** ответы, это как раз то, что *учит*. А аж 7 (минимум) человек, видимо абсолютно не разбираясь в *сути* проблемы, заминусовали его. Прямо мракобесие какое-то охватывает этот сайт.

Answer (score 4):

Ловите «эксперимент в реальности»:

```
import random

золото = 1
серебро = 0

сундук1 = [золото, золото]
сундук2 = [золото, серебро]

def эксперимент():
    сундук = random.choice((сундук1, сундук2))
    монета = random.choice(сундук)
    if монета == серебро:
        return  # этот случай не учитывается в условии
    return сундук.count(золото) == 2


всего = 10 ** 7
успехов = 0
проведено = 0
while проведено < всего:
    результат = эксперимент()
    if результат is not None:
        успехов += результат
        проведено += 1

print(успехов / проведено)
```

Результат одного из запусков — `0.6666651`

Comment: А зачем вы два рандома то делаете? Первая монета всегда золото, значит во второй строке нужно взять вторую монету. Замените  монета = random.choice(сундук) на монета = сундук[1].

Comment: Затем, что не вижу причин считать варианты G1->G2 и G2->G1 одинаковыми. (Как, впрочем, не вижу причин и для обратного, так что можно считать, что я слился)

Comment: @andreymal зря слились. это физически разные монеты, ваш код точно соответствует реальному положеню дел при вытаскивании.

Comment: @mikelsv заменять нелья, потому что тогда код перестает рассматривать случай, когда первой вытянули сундук1[1].

Answer (score 3):

Забудем на минутку, что мы достали. Рассмотрим события:

1. Мы выбрали первый сундук (вероятность 1/3) и достали монету, а затем вторую. Обе оказались золотыми. Вероятность этого исхода 1/3.
2. Мы выбрали второй сундук (вероятность 1/3) и достали монету. Он оказалась золотой. Следующая монета окажется серебряной. Вероятность этого исхода 1/6.
3. Мы выбрали второй сундук и достали монету. Он оказалась серебряной. Следующая монета окажется золотой. Вероятность этого исхода 1/6.
4. Мы выбрали третий сундук и достали монету. Он оказалась серебряной. Следующая тоже окажется серебряной. Вероятность этого исхода 1/3.

Они составляют полное вероятностное пространство.

Воспользуемся понятием [условной вероятности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C).

Вероятность того, что вторая монета золотая, при условии, что первая золотая, равна

```
P(первая и вторая золотые) / P(первая золотая) =
     = (1/3) /* случай 1 */ / (1/3 /* случай 1 */ + 1/6 /* случай 2 */) =
     = 2/3.
```

---

Если вы не верите математике, поверьте эксперименту. Вот программа, вычисляющая нужную вероятность:

```
using System;

enum Coin { Gold, Silver }
class Chest { public Coin[] Coins; }

public class Test
{
    static Random r = new Random();

    static Chest[] chests = new[]
    {
        new Chest { Coins = new [] { Coin.Gold, Coin.Gold } },
        new Chest { Coins = new [] { Coin.Gold, Coin.Silver } },
        new Chest { Coins = new [] { Coin.Silver, Coin.Silver } }
    };

    static void Experiment(out bool firstGold, out bool secondGold)
    {
        var chest = chests[r.Next(3)]; // случайный сундук
        var firstCoinIndex = r.Next(2); // достали случайную монету
        var secondCoindIndex = (firstCoinIndex == 0) ? 1 : 0;
        firstGold = chest.Coins[firstCoinIndex] == Coin.Gold;
        secondGold = chest.Coins[secondCoindIndex] == Coin.Gold;
    }

    static int totalExperimentsWithFirstGold = 0,
               totalSuccessfulExperiments = 0;

    static void Iteration()
    {
        bool firstGold, secondGold;
        do
        {
            Experiment(out firstGold, out secondGold);
        } while (!firstGold);

        totalExperimentsWithFirstGold++;
        if (secondGold)
            totalSuccessfulExperiments++;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            for (int batchIdx = 0; batchIdx < 1000; batchIdx++)
                Iteration();
            double currProbability = (double)totalSuccessfulExperiments /
                                        (double)totalExperimentsWithFirstGold;
            Console.Write("\rProbability = {0} after {1} iterations",
                            currProbability,
                            totalExperimentsWithFirstGold);
        }
    }
}
```

У меня выдаёт:

> Probability = 0,666607376906571 after 34486000 iterations

Comment: Вас ударило молнией, забудьте об этом на минутку и рассчитайте вероятность этого события. ) Зачем вы пытаетесь считать вероятность уже свершившихся событий, причем устанавливая вероятность не равную 100%?

Comment: @mikelsv: Посмотрите на формулу условной вероятности всё же. То, что вы пытаетесь найти — это именно условная вероятность. Она рассчитывается через полную вероятность так, как указано в статье Википедии.

Answer (score 3):

Раз уж пишем код...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $gold = 0;
my $total = 0;
my @boxes = ( ['g','s'], ['g','g'] );

while( $total < 1000000 )
{
  my $idx = int(rand(2));
  my $box = $boxes[ $idx ];
  $idx = int(rand(2));
  next if $box->[$idx] ne 'g';
  $idx ^= 1;
  $total++;
  $gold++ if $box->[$idx] eq 'g';
}
printf( "$gold from $total, %.4f\n", $gold/$total );
```

Comment: и? получили 0.667? :)

Comment: Само собой. Но это не ответ на вопрос, который задавался :)

Comment: это ответ именно на тот вопрос. это задача на условную вероятность. суть ее в том, что шанс оказаться над сундуком, в котором осталась золотая монета, в два раза выше, чем шанс, в котором осталась серебряная. хотя может быть и нет, тут все зависит от того, как воспринимать условие задачи :)

Answer (score 2):

Или золотая или нет, 50%. Если мы достаем одну золотую, значит вариант сундука с двумя серебряными отпадает. Получается, в этом сундуке, откуда мы достали золотую монету, либо серебряная либо золотая монета.

Comment: Угу, хорошее рассуждение. Вероятность того, что ваш ответ правильный, 50%: или да, или нет.

Answer (score 2):

После того, как вытащена золотая монета, задача "формально" сводится к тому, чтобы определить вероятности для каждого сундука, с которыми каждый из сундуков являются тем сундуком, из которого вытащена монета (извините за формулировку, я нарочно).

Для сундука с двумя серебряными вероятность оказаться сундуком, из которого вытащена золотая монета равна нулю.

Для сундука с двумя золотыми она в два раза больше, чем с одной золотой.
Т.к. больше сундуков нет, получаем x*2+x = 1

Таким образом мы с вероятностью 2/3 попали в сундук с двумя золотыми, и именно с этой вероятностью вторя монета золотая.

Может выглядеть странно, но представьте, что в сундуках по 1000 монет. В первом все золотые, во втором ТОЛЬКО ОДНА, в третьем все серебряные.
В этом случае, после того, как вытащили золотую монету уже житейская интуиция подскажет, что вряд ли нам так повезло вытащить "единственную" золотую из тысячи.

Answer (score 1):

Сундук с двумя серебряными для отвлечения внимания. Мы явно не их него тянем сейчас монеты. Отбросим его для упрощения. Термин "условная вероятность" тоже отбросим :) Решаем на пальцах:

Мы можем вытащить еще одну золотую монету **тогда и только тогда**, когда мы вытащили первую из сундука с двумя золотыми монетами. Таким образом, ответ полностью эквивалентен ответу на

> У нас в руках золотая монета. Какова вероятность того, что мы сейчас стоим с золотой монетой в руках у сундука, в котором изначально было две золотых монеты?

Который вообще не зависит от оставшегося содержимого сундуков (прощай бросание монетки и 50/50)! И который зависит **только** от событий, которые уже произошли (но исход которых мы не знаем).

Пусть у нас были монеты в двух сундуках

```
(G1, G2)
(G3, S)
```

Вытянули золотую. Значит есть три равновероятных исхода:

- Вытянули G1
- Вытянули G2
- Вытянули G3

Результат: золотая в случаях 2 из 3, 2/3

Интуитивная (ошибочная) оценка дает 1/2, потому что первые два случая воспринимаются как один. Чтобы это побороть, представьте что монет намного больше:

Пусть у нас будет два сундука - один с 500000 золотых, второй - с 499999 серебра и одним золотым. 
Вероятность, что мы сначала ткнули пальцем в сундук с серебром (но пока про это не знаем), а потом еще и вытащили одну золотую монету (и про это тоже не знаем) - один на миллион.

З.Ы. понятие "уже наступила" и вообще момент, в который произошло событие не имеет никакого отношения к теории вероятности. Важно лишь то, что мы пока не знаем исход. Я бросил кубик год назад, но не смотрел на результат. Какая вероятность что там выпало 5?

Comment: И вы туда же. Второй сундук тоже для отвлечения внимания. А вот такого эпичного объяснения я еще не видел.  Первые два варианта идентичны, я даже не понимаю, как их можно разделить вот так.

Comment: "*есть три равновероятных исхода*" - нет. Есть только 2 исхода: содержимое нашего сундука будет либо (G), либо (S).

Comment: @klopp ну естественно есть два исхода. но вероятность у них разная. выйти на улицу и встретить динозавра - тоже два возможных исхода - или встретите или нет! но вероятность у них разная. представьте что монеты действительно пронумерованы. проведите опыт с бумажками, в конце концов.

Comment: Странно. Сколько раз перечитываю формулировку задачи, столько же раз и НЕ вижу, где там зависимость от первого вытаскивания. Вопрос о вероятности вытаскивания голда *во второй попытке*, и только.

Comment: @klopp вот поэтому я и привел пример про динозавра - вы думаете, что нет никакой зависимости от того, вымерли они или нет? Вопрос о вероятности встретить динозавра, Представьте, что монеты реально пронумерованы с обратной стороны. Проведите реальный опыт, в конце концов.

Comment: Для опыта код чуть ниже :) Но к динозаврам этот вопрос, IMHO, не имеет отношения. Спрашивается о вероятности события в ситуации, которая **уже наступила**. Тщательней нужно быть с формулировками просто.

Comment: @klopp ваш код выдает 2/3 - потому что он делает именно то, что описано в моем ответе - рассматривает 3 равновероятных случая, отбрасывая 4-й. осталось дождаться топикастера, который напишет "берите всегда [1] вместо [$idx]!"

Comment: @klopp то, что событие событие наступило в прошлом, еще не значит что мы знаем его исход.